# Increment/Decrement and compiler

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x, y, z;
    printf("Enter x and y: ");
    scanf("%d%d", &x, &y);
    z = x++ + --y + (x<y);
    printf("z = %d\n", z);
    return 0;
}
```

For x = 1, y = 3, I'm getting z = 3 instead of 4, is this compiler related or am I wrong?

> z = 1++ + --3 + (1<3); z = 1 + 2 + (1<2); z = 3 + 1 = 4

Comment: Note - the undefinedness here is because you are updating `x` and `y` (`x++`, `--y`) *and* using them to compute a result (`x < y`) without an intervening sequence point.

Comment: @JohnBode z = 1++ + --3 + (1<3);
z = 1 + 2 + (1<2);
z = 3 + 1 = 4, what do you mean by that?

Comment: it doesn't matter what the values of the variables are - if you try to update a variable using `++` or `--` *and* use it to compute a value without an intervening sequence point, then the behavior is undefined and the result is not predictable, nor is it guaranteed to be consistent.  You'll have to compute `x < y` in a separate statement, save the result to another variable, and then add that to `z`.

Comment: @an9xia: How do you know that `x++ + --y + (x<y)` gives `1 + 3 + (1<3)` or `1 + 2 + (1<2)` or something else? Nothing in the C standard says that the `x<y` will use the values of `x` and `y` before or after the `++` and `--` operations. The fact that they are “preincrement” and “postincrement” only applies **directly** to `x++` and `--y`, not to appearances of `x` and `y` elsewhere in the expression. Worse than that, the C standard not only does not say which values of `x` and `y` will be used elsewhere, it explicitly says it does not define the behavior of the entire expression.

Comment: @EricPostpischil thank you so much, this answered my question. :)

Comment: @an9xia: Yeah, there's no well-defined result.  C does not force left-to-right evaluation, and it doesn't force `x++` or `--y` to be updated *immediately* after evaluation.  You can't assume that `x` in `x < y` is the value of `x` before or after the `++` operation.  The C language definition *specifically* calls this sort of thing out as "undefined behavior", meaning neither the compiler nor runtime environment are required to handle it in any particular way.  There's no guarantee that the result will be predictable or repeatable.